# Gmail app only partially syncing

Tags: sync, gmail, email, lenovo, imap

I've just bought a Lenovo B phone with Android.

I've added my Gmail account and have enabled the Gmail sync in the phone's settings. It has downloaded all my emails, however it won't properly sync which emails have been read or not.

I read a couple emails on my MacBook using Thunderbird... however on my new phone, the Gmail app says that these emails are `unread`.

I know it's not a problem with Thunderbird, because I also have a Samsung A3... and my mail on that phone is all up-to-date in terms of what emails are read / unread.

Also the sync settings in my Lenovo say that it has sync'd within the last few minutes (I originally set it up about 30 mins) and this was way after I read those couple emails. So it should have updated them by now.

Does anyone know what might be wrong?

**Edit:**

I tried sending myself an email using Thunderbird... it showed up on my phone where I then read it. Thunderbird then showed the email as `read`... however on my device those earlier emails that I read using Thunderbird are still showing as `unread`... very strange

Comment: @beeshyams thanks, I tried clearing the cache but with no luck... how do I reinstall the app as Android wont let me uninstall it? Do I remove / add my Google account again?

Comment: Also see this please ,,https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/2650727 - restarting device also helps

Comment: Good. You may self answer